# Neo4j : Using apoc calls/apis in where clause

Tags: neo4j

I have a query of the form

```
match (n:specified_label)-[r:specific_edge]->(m)
    where m.name contains 'word_1'
       or m.name contains 'word_2'
       or m.name contains 'word_3'
       ...
       or m.name contains 'word_100'
return m
```

I want to replace all the contains statements by a single function (can be a APOC plugin, or an API call, or anything), which accepts a single argument (m.name) and returns true/false based on whether m.name contains any of 'word_1' ... 'word_100' as a substring.

Note that 'word_1', 'word_2', ..'word_100' should be hardcoded in the implementation of the function, and not appear anywhere in the query.

```
match (n:specified_label)-[r:specified_edge]->(m)
    where is_good(m.name)
return m
```

Any leads will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
match (n:specified_label)-[r:specified_edge]->(m)
CALL stored.proc.isGood(m) YIELD result AS is_good
WITH n, r, m, is_good
WHERE is_good = TRUE
```

Just call the stored procedure normally, it will get called once for every row your match returns. Then filter the result using a regular old `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Procedures cannot be used in expressions. But you can write a procedure having a signature of:

```
Stream<NodeResult> isGood(@Name("node") Node n)
```

That either returns a one element stream containing n or an empty stream based on your logic. For NodeResult see https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/master/src/main/java/apoc/result/NodeResult.java.

With that your cypher looks like

```
match (n:specified_label)-[r:specified_edge]->(m)
call is_good(m) yield node
return node
```

#### note for upcoming Neo4j 3.1

Since 3.1.0-M09 there are user defined functions in addition to existing procedures. Functions can be used as part of expressions, e.g. in a where filter. However functions will be limited to perform read-only operations. See https://neo4j.com/release-notes/neo4j-3-1-0-m09/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using N separate `CONTAINS` terms or writing a custom procedure, you could use a single regular expression containing the N alternate names. This would also allow you to pass in the collection of alternate name strings as a [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters).

For example, this query joins the names in such a parameter (`words`) into a `|`-separated string, and then uses that in a single regular expression:

```
WITH REPLACE(TRIM(REDUCE(s = '', w IN {words} | s + w + ' ')), ' ', '|') AS ws
MATCH (n:specified_label)-[r:specific_edge]->(m)
WHERE m.name =~ ('.*' + ws + '.*')
RETURN m;
```